# Why Angular custom directive scope effects parent controller scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a custom directive, which shows a list and select-box.

Please follow the code below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Template</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/home/rahul/Installers/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/rahul/Installers/Bootstrapv3.0.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/rahul/Installers/Bootstrapv3.0.2/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/home/rahul/Installers/Bootstrapv3.0.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/home/rahul/Installers/angular.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module("app",[]);
        angular.module("app").controller("myctrl",myctrl);
        angular.module("app").controller("childCtrl",childCtrl);
        angular.module("app").directive("loadFilms",loadFilms);

        myctrl.$inject = ["$scope"];
        childCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];

        function myctrl($scope){
            var vm = this;
            vm.title = "Directive and nested scoping";
            vm.actorName = "Amithabh Bachhan";
            $scope.year = ["70's","80's","90's"];
        }

        function childCtrl($scope){
            var vm = this;

            vm.selectedYear = "";

            vm.moviesObj = {
                "70's" : ["Anand","Lawaris","Kala Pathhar","Deewar","Amar Akbar Anthony","Mili"],
                "80's" : ["Sharabi","Kaalia","Silsila","Satte Pe Satta","Nastik","Shahensha"],
                "90's" : ["Hum","Aaj Ka Arjun", "Ajooba","Khuda Gawah","Ganga Jamuna Saraswati","Lal Badshah"]
            }

            vm.movies = [];

            vm.getMovies = function(){
                vm.movies = vm.moviesObj[vm.selectedYear];
            }
        }

        function loadFilms(){
            return {
                restrict : "EA",
                controller : "childCtrl",
                controllerAs : "vm",
                scope : true,
                template : function(tElem, tAttrs){
                    var str = "<select ng-model='vm.selectedYear' data-ng-options='y as y for y in year' " + "class='form-control' ng-change='vm.getMovies()'>" + 
                    "<option value=''>Select</option>" + 
                    "</select>" +
                    "<br />" + 
                    "<ol class='slide-animate-container'>" + 
                    "   <li class='slide-animate' ng-repeat='m in vm.movies'>{{m}}</li>"+
                    "</ol>";
                    return str;
                }
            } 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myctrl as vm" class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>{{vm.title}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h5>{{vm.actorName}}</h5>                       
                </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" load-films></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The directive "load-films" has its own scope,

The values to the select-box in the directive are passed from the parent scope variable from the enclosing controller "myctrl".

The working example is in the link
[Example One](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulshivsharan/knfyz57e/6/)

Now, once I change the scope of the directive "load-films" to `false`

like

```
 function loadFilms(){
            return {
                restrict : "EA",
                controller : "childCtrl",
                controllerAs : "vm",
                scope : false,
                template : function(tElem, tAttrs){
                    var str = "<select ng-model='vm.selectedYear' data-ng-options='y as y for y in year' " + "class='form-control' ng-change='vm.getMovies()'>" + 
                    "<option value=''>Select</option>" + 
                    "</select>" +
                    "<br />" + 
                    "<ol class='slide-animate-container'>" + 
                    "   <li class='slide-animate' ng-repeat='m in vm.movies'>{{m}}</li>"+
                    "</ol>";
                    return str;
                }
            } 
        }
```

The values `vm.title` and `vm.actorName` of the parent controller don't load in the UI.

Why ?

Ideally `vm.title` and `vm.actorName` are in the controller "myCtrl", so how does setting the `scope` property to `false` of the directive affect the parent controller variables, as the
variable `actorName` and `title` are attached to `this` not to `$scope`.

The working example using `{.., scope = false,..}` is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulshivsharan/b0gvtjg9/2/)

Comment: Change `scope:false` to `scope: {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LONG ANSWER:** Answer lies in name conversion and initialization query.
If you debug what is initializing you will detect that:

1. First is `myctrl`;
2. Second is `childCtrl`.

If you are using `scope: true` next steps are applied:

1. Create `$scope` for `myctrl` and assign `$scope.vm = myctrl` (`myctrl as vm`);
2. Create `$scope` for `childCtrl` and assign `$scope.vm = childCtrl` (`controllerAs: mv`);
3. `vm.title` and `vm.actorName` are taken from `$scope.vm` from 1st step.

What happens if `scope: false`:

1. Create `$scope` for `myctrl` and assign `$scope.vm = myctrl` (`myctrl as vm`);
2. Use already created `$scope` for `myctrl` where `$scope.vm` already exists;
3. When initializing directive - rewrite `$scope.vm` with `childCtrl` (`controllerAs: 'vm'`);
4. `vm.title` and `vm.actorName` are taken from `$scope.vm` from 3rd step (from `childCtrl` isntead of `myctrl`).

**SHORT ANSWER:**
After initialization of every controller, you still remember relation of controller to `$scope.vm` **BUT** in `$scope.vm` you have `childCtrl` instead of `myctrl`, as it was overwritten during directive initialization and `$scope` is shared. And `vm.title` and `vm.actorName` are not part if `childCtrl`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using same name (`vm`) for both `controllerAs`. Thus the variable is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of both controllerAs and scope in your directive.

**controllerAs** because it is forcing *vm.* in your view to be an alias to properties on your directive's controller rather than the alias defined in your outer view, and **scope** because you don't need it when setting it to false.

However, even though that will fix it, it is not the ideal approach. Ideally you should keep your **controllerAs** and have **scope** looking like this

```
scope : {
  title : "@"
}
```

and then change your view to use the title passed in from

```
<blah load-films title="vm.title"/>
```

[Directives with isolated scope](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope) are the better way to go, so stick with **controllerAs** and **scope** but ensure the value you want on the parent is passed in explicitly via a parameter - this way you don't need to rely on the view containing your directive to set up the view with a specific alias like "vm" (magic strings are bad)